# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFullYear' of null (ANGULAR)

Tags: angular, function, ionic-framework, scheduler, ionic2-calendar

I am trying to create a scheduler using ionic2-calendar but I keep getting this error in the console when I want to save the event. Could it be an error when installing the ionic2-calendar npm package?

```
core.js:6479 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFullYear' of null
    at MonthViewComponent.onDataLoaded (ionic2-calendar.js:1768)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (ionic2-calendar.js:1576)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at Subject.next (Subject.js:39)
    at CalendarService.loadEvents (ionic2-calendar.js:1492)
    at CalendarComponent.loadEvents (ionic2-calendar.js:3596)
    at schedule.page.ts:134
```

Here is my code "scheduler.page.ts". Is there anything I could be missing from the code for the function to work?

```
import { CalendarComponent } from 'ionic2-calendar';
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, Inject, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { CalModalPage } from '../cal-modal/cal-modal.page';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-schedule',
  templateUrl: 'schedule.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['schedule.page.scss'],
})
export class SchedulePage implements OnInit {
  eventSource = [];
  viewTitle: string;
 
  calendar = {
    mode: 'month',
    currentDate: new Date()
  };
 
  selectedDate: Date;

  @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCal: CalendarComponent;
 
  constructor(
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string,
    private modalCtrl: ModalController
  ) {}
 
  ngOnInit() {}
 

  loadEvents() {
    this.eventSource = this.createRandomEvents();
  }

  createRandomEvents() {
    var events = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i += 1) {
        var date = new Date();
        var eventType = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        var startDay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) - 45;
        var endDay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + startDay;
        var startTime;
        var endTime;
        if (eventType === 0) {
            startTime = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate() + startDay));
            if (endDay === startDay) {
                endDay += 1;
            }
            endTime = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate() + endDay));
            events.push({
                title: 'All Day - ' + i,
                startTime: startTime,
                endTime: endTime,
                allDay: true
            });
        } else {
            var startMinute = Math.floor(Math.random() * 24 * 60);
            var endMinute = Math.floor(Math.random() * 180) + startMinute;
            startTime = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + startDay, 0, date.getMinutes() + startMinute);
            endTime = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + endDay, 0, date.getMinutes() + endMinute);
            events.push({
                title: 'Event - ' + i,
                startTime: startTime,
                endTime: endTime,
                allDay: false
            });
        }
    }
    return events;
  } 
  
  // Change current month/week/day
  next() {
    this.myCal.slideNext();
  }
 
  back() {
    this.myCal.slidePrev();
  }
 
  // Selected date reange and hence title changed
  onViewTitleChanged(title) {
    this.viewTitle = title;
  }
 
  // Calendar event was clicked
  async onEventSelected(event) {
    // Use Angular date pipe for conversion
    let start = formatDate(event.startTime, 'medium', this.locale);
    let end = formatDate(event.endTime, 'medium', this.locale);
 
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: event.title,
      subHeader: event.desc,
      message: 'From: ' + start + '<br><br>To: ' + end,
      buttons: ['OK'],
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  async openCalModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: CalModalPage,
      cssClass: 'cal-modal',
      backdropDismiss: false
    });
   
    await modal.present();
   
    modal.onDidDismiss().then((result) => {
      if (result.data && result.data.event) {
        let event = result.data.event;
        if (event.allDay) {
          let start = event.startTime;
          event.startTime = new Date(
            Date.UTC(
              start.getUTCFullYear(),
              start.getUTCMonth(),
              start.getUTCDate()
            )
          );
          event.endTime = new Date(
            Date.UTC(
              start.getUTCFullYear(),
              start.getUTCMonth(),
              start.getUTCDate() + 1
            )
          );
        }
        this.eventSource.push(result.data.event);
        this.myCal.loadEvents();
      }
    });
  }
  
  removeEvents() {
    this.eventSource = [];
  }
 
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use Momentjs

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your `createRandomEvents` function `else` case startTime & endTime code as follows.

```
createRandomEvents() {
    var events = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i += 1) {
        var date = new Date();
        var eventType = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        var startDay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) - 45;
        var endDay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + startDay;
        var startTime;
        var endTime;
        if (eventType === 0) {
            startTime = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate() + startDay));
            if (endDay === startDay) {
                endDay += 1;
            }
            endTime = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate() + endDay));
            events.push({
                title: 'All Day - ' + i,
                startTime: startTime,
                endTime: endTime,
                allDay: true
            });
        } else {
            var startMinute = Math.floor(Math.random() * 24 * 60);
            var endMinute = Math.floor(Math.random() * 180) + startMinute;
            startTime = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate() + startDay, 0, date.getUTCMinutes() + startMinute);
            endTime = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate() + endDay, 0, date.getUTCMinutes() + endMinute);
            events.push({
                title: 'Event - ' + i,
                startTime: startTime,
                endTime: endTime,
                allDay: false
            });
        }
    }
    return events;
  }
```